# Google Earth Pro - can't change height

Tags: shapefile, google-earth, extrude

I am trying to import some line data representing utilities into GE Pro. However they get a really high offset (pic 1). I've tried changing the height in the "style template" menu that you can choose when you import the shp data. "Hoogte" is height in my language and I've put it to 0. However as you can see in pic 1 they keep having a really high offset. I've tried setting "Hoogte" to all sorts of different values to no avail. In pic 3 I have another menu from you can navigate to by right clicking the layer in GE pro. Here I am able to successfully change the height, but it messes up the colour scheme and I can't put it back to the required colours.

TLDR: I want to put this shp data at ground level and not have a 50m offset.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ** <extrude>** tag extends the line down to the ground. https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut (change that value will reduce the heights)